Kotlin Multiplatform - what is replacement for product flavours?
I need help understanding how to create different application versions in the Kotlin Multiplatform project using the common codebase. In a 'classic' Android project I would create productFlavours e.g. applicationA and applicationB, appropriate sourceSet directories, and then put product-flavour-specific files in the source sets.

Every product flavor has its own Application class, where different libraries are initialized, MainActivity class, where a different navigation graph is created, and also own resource files (colors.xml, settings.xml), and in particular most important google-services.json file for the configuration with a desired Firebase project.

How can I achieve the same result in the Kotlin Multiplatform project? Is it ever possible? If you have an idea how to resolve such a case I and many other people will be grateful for the detailed description.

have you found any solution for this problem?

Unfortunately not. I'm still looking for a suitable solution

This post might give you some ideas how to achieve "flavor" like functionality in multiplatform project. You can find there link to this example repository.
There is library BuildKonfig which lets you create BuildConfig file in multiplatform project.
This might help you to further customize your runtime.
buildkonfig {
    packageName = "com.your.packagename"
    objectName = "BuildConfig"
    exposeObjectWithName = "BuildConfig"

    defaultConfigs {
        buildConfigField(STRING, "ApiUrl", "http://localhost:9668")
        buildConfigField(STRING, "apiKey", "apiKey")
        buildConfigField(STRING, "secret", "secret")
    }

    defaultConfigs("debug") {
        buildConfigField(STRING, "ApiUrl", "http://localhost2:9668")
        buildConfigField(STRING, "apiKey", "apiKey2")
        buildConfigField(STRING, "secret", "secret2")
    }

    defaultConfigs("release") {
        buildConfigField(STRING, "ApiUrl", "http://192.168.66.90")
        buildConfigField(STRING, "apiKey", "apiKey3")
        buildConfigField(STRING, "secret", "secret3")
    }
}

To build you project just use:
./gradlew proguardDesktop --project-prop buildkonfig.flavor=release


I saw the BuildKonig library, but it seems to work only for simple build config fields, which is not enough for me. I have cases where I must provide different implementations of the class depending on the product flavor and only that product flavor has access to some external dependencies. To provide you with some scale, currently, I build 27 different versions of the app from the same codebase by using 3 build types combined with 9 product flavors - every variant has a specific mainclass implementation and resource set.
Maybe moving to the build types only mentioned in Slack is a good idea.

One can as well define productFlavors in app_android/build.gradle.kts.
This only works for Android, but one can at least cover different vendors.
There's even a "Kotlin Multiplatform Wizard": https://kmp.jetbrains.com.

I need a solution for both platforms - Android and iOS. Partially, the solution is not enough for me.
